# Flutter - 'onSurface' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use disabledForegroundColor and disabledBackgroundColor instead

Tags: flutter, dart

In `flutter` version `3.3.0` `ElevatedButton` `onSurface` is deprecated i am confused which property should i use instead `onSurface`. should i use `disabledForegroundColor` or `disabledBackgroundColor` or Both?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you need to change both text and button color for disabled state, you should use both `disabledForegroundColor` and `disabledBackgroundColor`.

But

using normally only the `disabledBackgroundColor` should be enough for the button.

Answer (score 0):

Use `foregroundColor` and `disabledForegroundColor` instead of  `onSurface`.

```dart
style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
  foregroundColor:Colors.red,
  disabledForegroundColor:Colors.green,
```